# Reading 150mb file in BeautifulSoup in Python taking too long

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I start executing this code:

```
URL = r"C:\Users\jarze\PycharmProjects\CSV-modifier\venv\html.html"
html_report_part1 = open(URL, 'r', encoding="UTF-8")
html_text = ''
for line in html_report_part1.readlines():
    html_text += line
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
```

The file is actually quite big (150 mb), but when i open it in chrome it is loading quickly. This code is executing for 5 hours for now and still is in progress. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: You could try another parser, i.e. `lxml` instead of Python's `html.parser` but that's just a random guess. You can read about parsers here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Comment: I have generated a 200MB html and will run some tests on it. Where do you want the answer? You have two threads.. @Michal

Comment: Even with a old computer i can read in the whole file. And read it line by line takes 20 minutes. No matter if i use html.parser or lxml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without access to a file of your size, I am wondering if this yields a better result?:

```
URL = r"C:\Users\jarze\PycharmProjects\CSV-modifier\venv\html.html"
with open(URL, 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.read(), "html.parser")
```

Essentially you're not iterating through the files.  But just reading the whole file.

Comment: After a little bit of time its return MemoryError

Comment: Interesting.  While parsing BeautifulSoup, or after?

Comment: As commented above by Gregor - dit you try another parser?